# how i change a class when the radio label is clicked

Tags: javascript, radio-button

I want to change a class when I click on the button

I'm trying with this code in the header:

```js
$(function() {
  // When the value of the radio change
  $('.radioPanel [type="radio"]').on('change', function() {
    $(this)
      .prev().addClass('red')
      .siblings().removeClass('red');
  });
});
```

```css
.rp-recuadro {
  border: 2px solid #2e3180;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  margin: 0px 20px;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.red {
  background: #2e3180;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="step1">
  <div class="secciones">
    <h2>¿Cuántos vehículos tienes?</h2>
    <div class="rp-flex">
      <div><label class="rp-recuadro"><input type="radio" name="nombreDeVariable1" value="A"> Opción A</label></div>
      <div><label class="rp-recuadro"><input type="radio" name="nombreDeVariable1" value="B"> Opción B</label></div>
      <div><label class="rp-recuadro"><input type="radio" name="nombreDeVariable1" value="C"> Opción C</label></div>
    </div>
    <button type="button" onclick="goToNextStep(1)">Continuar</button>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Want to change the color of selected radio button or other than that?

Comment: where is element with "radioPanel" class?

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please add relevant code and explanation for a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```js
var rad = document.myForm.nombreDeVariable1;

for (var i = 0; i < rad.length; i++) {
    rad[i].addEventListener('change', function() {
         $('.red').removeClass('red');
         $(this).parent().addClass('red');
       
    });
}
```

```css
.rp-recuadro{
    border: 2px solid #2e3180;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    margin: 0px 20px;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.red {
    background: #2e3180;
    color: white;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="step1">
    <div class="secciones">
        <h2>¿Cuántos vehículos tienes?</h2>
        <div class="rp-flex">
        <form name="myForm">
            <div><label class="rp-recuadro"><input type="radio" name="nombreDeVariable1" value="A" cla> Opción A</label></div>
            <div><label class="rp-recuadro"><input type="radio" name="nombreDeVariable1" value="B"> Opción B</label></div>
            <div><label class="rp-recuadro"><input type="radio" name="nombreDeVariable1" value="C"> Opción C</label></div>
        </div>
        <button type="button" onclick="goToNextStep(1)">Continuar</button>
    </div>
    </form>
</section>
```

Comment: Great, where i put this code* sorry if is a dump question, i get a error in the console

var rad = document.myForm.nombreDeVariable1;

for (var i = 0; i < rad.length; i++) {
    rad[i].addEventListener('change', function() {
         $('.red').removeClass('red');
         $(this).parent().addClass('red');
       
    });
}

Comment: I try this in the here: http://welovewebs.com/dev/eloqua/ and its not working, give me a error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nombreDeVariable1' of undefined at eloqua.js:1

Comment: @RobertoPuente all element need to under   <form name="myForm">

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function() {

  var $radios = $('.rp-recuadro input[type=radio]');
  $radios.on('change', function() {
     $radios.removeClass('red');
     $radios.filter(':checked').addClass('red');
  });
});
```

```css
.rp-recuadro {
  border: 2px solid #2e3180;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  margin: 0px 20px;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.red {
  background: #2e3180;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="step1">
  <div class="secciones">
    <h2>¿Cuántos vehículos tienes?</h2>
    <div class="rp-flex">
      <div>
      <label class="rp-recuadro"><input type="radio" name="nombreDeVariable1" value="A"> Opción A</label></div>
      <div><label class="rp-recuadro"><input type="radio" name="nombreDeVariable1" value="B"> Opción B</label></div>
      <div><label class="rp-recuadro"><input type="radio" name="nombreDeVariable1" value="C"> Opción C</label></div>
    </div>
    <button type="button" onclick="goToNextStep(1)">Continuar</button>
  </div>
</section>
```

First edit you're selector and try this code.

```
  var $radios = $('.rp-recuadro input[type=radio]');
  $radios.on('change', function() {
     $radios.removeClass('red');
     $radios.filter(':checked').addClass('red');
  });
```

Comment: Please create a snippet (you can even copy OP's to your editor) and test your answer

Comment: The code above add a red class to the input button. for the demo there is a link https://jsfiddle.net/buATP/